bibentry command works but throws errors with abbrvnat-fr bibliography style
My preferred bibliography management package is natbib with the abbrvnat bibliography style. I am writing a document in French which requires full article citations in the text body. \bibentry from the bibentry package provides this and works fine with abbrvnat, but when I switched my bibliography language to French with the abbrvnat-fr bibliography style, it gave me a bunch of errors. The weird thing is that it actually works fine, meaning it gives me the intended result on the page. Can anyone help me figure out what's going on?
Apparently there is a similar issue with chicago style but the fix doesn't work for me.
Here is the minimal working example:
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat-fr}
\usepackage{bibentry} % for in-body full bib entries
\nobibliography*

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\title{bibentry command fails with abbrvnat-fr bibliography style}

\date{}
\author{}
\maketitle

\section{Test}
    
\bibentry{aiayn}

\bibliography{biblio.bib}
\end{document}

Result:

This is the error I get (I actually get it 8 times in the log, but that number depends on the article(s) I cite):
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...egroup {}, N.~\bgroup \fonteauteurs 
                                                  \bgroup Parmar\egroup \egr...
l.24 \bibentry{aiayn}
                     
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


This answer to a different but related question mentions adding \global before \def in the macros used by bibentry. Replacing every occurrence of \def with \global\def in the abbrvnat-fr.bst file fixed the issue. However, I'm wary of unintended side-effects.
